# Android Studio Version 2.0 Emulator Not Starting

Tags: android, android-emulator

just updated my Android Studio to the latest Version 2.0. Now when I try to launch emulator, its not starting. I mean android studio's default emulator. Is there anybody who can instruct me on how to fix this?

Comment: I'm getting  below error when I try to run emulator-x86.exe directly from command line. 



---------------------------
emulator-x86.exe - System Error
---------------------------
The program can't start because Qt5Core.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem. 
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------

Comment: See my answer to this same problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36583172/3386826).

Comment: Have try this Link  may be it help .......  http://stackoverflow.com/a/37679624/5305430