# Cannot launch AVD in emulator Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

Problem with emulator in android studio 2...

Cannot launch AVD in emulator

```
Output:
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  47
  Current serial number in output stream:  46
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  6 (X_GLXIsDirect)
  Serial number of failed request:  47
  Current serial number in output stream:  46
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
emulator: WARNING: VM heap size set below hardware specified minimum of 384MB
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
emulator: WARNING: Setting VM heap size to 384MB
  Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
  Value in failed request:  0x0
  Serial number of failed request:  33
  Current serial number in output stream:  34
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

and this is in Console:

[image: Error]

and when running command for that answer it gives me `bash: cd: /android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/lib64/libstdc++: No such file or directory`

please guys help....

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Problem with the **Sdk path**.....

Linked the **Sdk path** instead of **$ANDROID_HOME**

```
  cd $ANDROID_HOME/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/lib64/libstdc++
  mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
  ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 $ANDROID_HOME/android-sdk-linux_x86/tools/lib64/libstdc++
```

In my case **using path** like that

```
 1. cd Desktop/blackgoogle/Android/Sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++
 2. mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak
 3. cd
 4. ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 Desktop/blackgoogle/Android/Sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++
```

**Note:-pathOfSDK/tools/lib64/libstdc++**

**Possibly duplicate** of [Cannot start Emulator in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36554322/cannot-start-emulator-in-android-studio-2-0/36568949?noredirect=1#comment62825094_36568949)

Comment: please elaborate what is happening there,how do i do that.

Comment: @VikasPandey copy your sdk path and put in the SDKPAth/tools/libstdc++. Its moving some file from one folder to another and creating link of the file (like shortcut file ).

Answer (score 32):

Pick "Software" in the Emulated Performance Graphics option, in the AVD settings instead of "Automatic"

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This for me overcame the issu `Emulator: libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so ...`, but when launching the emulator (Nexus_5X_API_27_x86), everything is black, even if I power up (I am a newbiew, so it may be a trivial issue).

Answer (score 5):

Use the below 3 commands to solve this error.

```
mv ~/Android/Sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6{,.bak}
mv ~/Android/Sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6.0.18{,.bak}
ln -s /usr/lib/libstdc++.so  ~/Android/Sdk/tools/lib64/libstdc++/
```

Comment: On Ubuntu 17.04, the paths were a bit different: `mv ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6{,.bak}` and `mv ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6.0.18{,.bak}` as well as `ln -s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/libstdc++.so ~Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++/`

Comment: On ubuntu 17.10 the paths changed again:
`mv ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6{,.bak}`
`mv ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6.0.18{,‌​.bak}`
`ln -s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libstdc++.so ~Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++/`

Comment: @Andres for copy and paster's the last line in Andres comment is missing a / between ~Android. Should be: ln -s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libstdc++.so ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++