# Linux - run android emulator on Nouveau driver

Tags: linux, android-emulator, segmentation-fault, nvidia

Linux (Debian Sid x64), kernel 4.14, Nvidia GPU. I am unable to run Android emulator on open Nouveau drivers. There is no any error message that I can post, jus segmentation fault. When I choose software rendering, it works but unusable (it runs very slow).

Does anybody know any workaround for that, or I am forced to use official Nvidia drivers?

Comment: same here. ubuntu 18.04 bionic.

Comment: this mgght help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37653391/cannot-launch-avd-in-emulator-android-studio

Comment: No, unfortunately

Comment: right. also stuck on nvidia, now! a pain, with suspend not working on a laptop.

Comment: I had a similar problem with Rstudio (it is quite famous bug on rstudio)
It is proposed by someone to run it using the following command in terminal:
QT_XCB_FORCE_SOFTWARE_OPENGL=1 rstudio