# Genymotion not showing virtual device

Tags: linux-device-driver, nvidia, genymotion

Clean Genymotion 2.12.1 installation in LMDE 2 (64b, Cinnamon 3.4.6, GeForce 210, 16GB RAM), VirtualBox 5.1.32.
When I launch a virtual device it shows the window for a few seconds and then disappear. In VirtualBox it shows as Running. I am suspecting video driver problem but IIRC it used to work. I had an existing installation which did not work so I perform the fresh intall.

The terminal output is

```
Logging activities to file: /home/denispyr/.Genymobile/genymotion.log
Logging activities to file: /home/denispyr/.Genymobile/genymotion.log
Logging activities to file: /home/denispyr/.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed/Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280/genymotion-player.log
nouveau: kernel rejected pushbuf: No such file or directory
nouveau: ch0: krec 0 pushes 0 bufs 1 relocs 0
nouveau: ch0: buf 00000000 00000004 00000004 00000004 00000000
```

The genymotion log

```
2018-05-12T21:36:21+03:00 [:18600] [debug] ("/mnt/work-data/testdel/genymotion/player", "--vm-name", "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280")
2018-05-12T21:36:21+03:00 [player:18600] [warning] libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Loading "vboxmanage" plugin
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Plugin "vboxmanage" loaded
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Chipset: "AuthenticAMD"
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] CPUID 0x80000001 (AMD): ECX= "1ebbfff"
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Path: "VBoxManage"
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("list", "hostinfo")
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] [System properties] Online physical CPU number: 6
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] [System properties] Online virtual CPU number: 6
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] CPU number is > 8 - Fix max number to 8
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] [System properties] Max CPU number: 8
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] [System properties] Max memory size: 16025
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] get "vboxnet0" from host.only.interface
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] [findHostOnlyInterface] Looking for compatible host-only interface
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("list", "hostonlyifs")
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Empty interface name
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] [createHostOnlyInterface] Must delete the old one "vboxnet0"
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] [deleteHostOnlyInterface] Deleting "vboxnet0" host-only interface
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("hostonlyif", "remove", "vboxnet0")
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [critical] [VBox] Return code: 1
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [critical] [VBox] Output command: "VBoxManage: error: The host network interface named 'vboxnet0' could not be found
VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_INVALID_ARG (0x80070057), component HostWrap, interface IHost, callee nsISupports
VBoxManage: error: Context: "FindHostNetworkInterfaceByName(Bstr(pszName).raw(), hif.asOutParam())" at line 139 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp"
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] [deleteHostOnlyInterface] "vboxnet0" could not be found
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] erase host.only.interface
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] [createHostOnlyInterface] Creating new host-only interface
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("hostonlyif", "create")
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] [createHostOnlyInterface] Interface "vboxnet0" created with success
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("list", "hostonlyifs")
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("hostonlyif", "ipconfig", "vboxnet0", "--ip", "192.168.56.1", "--netmask", "255.255.255.0")
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("dhcpserver", "remove", "--ifname", "vboxnet0")
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [critical] [VBox] Return code: 2
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [critical] [VBox] Output command: "VBoxManage: error: DHCP server does not exist"
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("dhcpserver", "add", "--ifname", "vboxnet0", "--ip", "192.168.56.100", "--netmask", "255.255.255.0", "--lowerip", "192.168.56.101", "--upperip", "192.168.56.254", "--enable")
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] [createHostOnlyInterface] DHCP server created with success
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] set "vboxnet0" to host.only.interface
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] [createHostOnlyInterface] "vboxnet0" host-only interface is ready to use
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("--version")
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] VM engine version: "5.1.32r120294"
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("showvminfo", "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280")
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:22+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "enumerate", "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280")
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("showvminfo", "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280")
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("showvminfo", "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280")
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
```

The genymotion player log

```
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] Proxy configuration: no proxy used
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] Host date and time: "12 May 2018 21:36:23 +0300"
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] Proxy configuration: no proxy used
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [qt.network.ssl.warning] QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [qt.network.ssl.warning] QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [critical] File:  "/home/xxxx/.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed//Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280/.flag"  Already exists, player may have crashed before.
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] GET  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/content/video/" ) 
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] "Local socket created at path: /tmp/ec4890ea1f371f139172b4fc45db2414"
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [warning] ****  STARTING VIRTUAL DEVICE  ****
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [warning] Player version: "2.12.1"
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] Checking device compatibility
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] Received message "PING"
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("showvminfo", "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280")
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] Trying to log in as "xxxx"
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] POST  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/launchpad/login/" ) 
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] Virtual Machine status: on
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] Trying to reconnect...
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] Boot successful
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] Genymotion system started. Attributed IP address:  "192.168.56.102"
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("showvminfo", "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280")
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [warning] QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] "Publisher settings is not connected"
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] Error: "Publisher settings is not connected"
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [warning] error with device connection "Publisher settings is not connected"
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] "subscriber" is connected, context 0x7faff400d730
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] "publisher" is connected, context 0x7faf88001950
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] Player running. Try to show window...
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [TemplateUuid] Device "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280" has template uuid property "c41a277f-39a1-402c-bf92-34d86732f89d"
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [emugl.debug] RenderWindow: CMD_INITIALIZE w=768 h=1280
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [emugl.debug] FrameBuffer::initialize
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [emugl.debug] call eglInitialize
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [emugl.debug] egl: 1 4
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("showvminfo", "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280")
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [emugl.debug] attempting to create egl context
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [emugl.debug] attempting to create egl pbuffer context
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [emugl.debug] context creation successful
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [emugl.debug] attempting to make context current
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [emugl.debug] context-current successful
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [emugl.debug] host system has enough extensions
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [emugl.debug] There are sufficient EGLconfigs available
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [emugl.debug] basic EGL initialization successful
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [emugl.debug] OpenGL renderer initialized successfully
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] OpenGL connected to: "192.168.56.102" : 25000
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] Port 22468 will be used for OpenGL data connections
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [Adb][logcat] "/home/xxxx/.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed/Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280/logcat-J18600.txt" : "192.168.56.102"
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-05-12T21:36:25+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:25+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [Adb][shell] ("getprop", "dev.bootcomplete")
2018-05-12T21:36:25+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [Adb][shell] full command: "/mnt/work-data/testdel/genymotion/tools/adb" -s "192.168.56.102" shell ("getprop",    2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] Proxy configuration: no proxy used
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] Host date and time: "12 May 2018 21:36:23 +0300"
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] Proxy configuration: no proxy used
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [qt.network.ssl.warning] QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_client_method
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [qt.network.ssl.warning] QSslSocket: cannot resolve SSLv2_server_method
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [critical] File:  "/home/xxxx/.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed//Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280/.flag"  Already exists, player may have crashed before.
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] GET  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/content/video/" ) 
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] "Local socket created at path: /tmp/ec4890ea1f371f139172b4fc45db2414"
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [warning] ****  STARTING VIRTUAL DEVICE  ****
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [warning] Player version: "2.12.1"
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] Checking device compatibility
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] Received message "PING"
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("showvminfo", "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280")
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] Trying to log in as "xxxx"
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] POST  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/launchpad/login/" ) 
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] Virtual Machine status: on
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] Trying to reconnect...
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] Boot successful
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] Genymotion system started. Attributed IP address:  "192.168.56.102"
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("showvminfo", "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280")
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [warning] QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
2018-05-12T21:36:23+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] "Publisher settings is not connected"
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] Error: "Publisher settings is not connected"
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [warning] error with device connection "Publisher settings is not connected"
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] "subscriber" is connected, context 0x7faff400d730
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] "publisher" is connected, context 0x7faf88001950
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] Player running. Try to show window...
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [TemplateUuid] Device "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280" has template uuid property "c41a277f-39a1-402c-bf92-34d86732f89d"
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [emugl.debug] RenderWindow: CMD_INITIALIZE w=768 h=1280
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [emugl.debug] FrameBuffer::initialize
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [emugl.debug] call eglInitialize
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [emugl.debug] egl: 1 4
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("showvminfo", "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280")
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [emugl.debug] attempting to create egl context
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [emugl.debug] attempting to create egl pbuffer context
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [emugl.debug] context creation successful
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [emugl.debug] attempting to make context current
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [emugl.debug] context-current successful
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [emugl.debug] host system has enough extensions
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [emugl.debug] There are sufficient EGLconfigs available
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [emugl.debug] basic EGL initialization successful
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [emugl.debug] OpenGL renderer initialized successfully
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] OpenGL connected to: "192.168.56.102" : 25000
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] Port 22468 will be used for OpenGL data connections
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [Adb][logcat] "/home/xxxx/.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed/Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280/logcat-J18600.txt" : "192.168.56.102"
2018-05-12T21:36:24+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Call: ("guestproperty", "get", "Custom Phone - 7.1.0 - API 25 - 768x1280", "androvm_ip_management")
2018-05-12T21:36:25+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [VBox] Return code: 0
2018-05-12T21:36:25+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [Adb][shell] ("getprop", "dev.bootcomplete")
2018-05-12T21:36:25+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [Adb][shell] full command: "/mnt/work-data/testdel/genymotion/tools/adb" -s "192.168.56.102" shell ("getprop", "dev.bootcomplete")
2018-05-12T21:36:25+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [Adb][shell] ("getprop", "dev.bootcomplete")  - exit code:  0
2018-05-12T21:36:25+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] "User xxxx (xxxx@xxxx.xxxx) logged on Hub"
2018-05-12T21:36:25+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] POST  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/licenses/activation/" )  "dev.bootcomplete")
2018-05-12T21:36:25+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] [Adb][shell] ("getprop", "dev.bootcomplete")  - exit code:  0
2018-05-12T21:36:25+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] "User xxxx (xxxx@xxxx.xxxx) logged on Hub"
2018-05-12T21:36:25+03:00 [Genymotion Player:18600] [debug] POST  QUrl( "https://cloud.genymotion.com/licenses/activation/" )
```

Comment: This looks like a silent crash. Can you try to either 1) enable core dumps and reproduce the bug or 2) run Genymotion through Valgrind (using --trace-children=yes) ?

Comment: Hey Aurelien :) Using `./genymotion  --trace-children=yes`, produced the this [genymotion log](https://pastebin.com/F4fTBDY2) and this [player log](https://pastebin.com/ShxGqa3N)

Comment: Ah, I was not clear: I would like to see Valgrind outputs rather than the app log files.

Comment: Hey Aurelien :) I ran `valgrind --leak-check=full --log-file=valgrind.log --track-origins=yes genymotion` and I got this [valgrind log](https://pastebin.com/0RqCJn6w). A far as I can tell the leak is repating so I stripped 1.5 MB of it.

Comment: Thanks for the Valgrind logs. Unfortunately I was not able to figure out the issue from them, but I somehow missed that your terminal output said "nouveau: kernel rejected pushbuf: No such file or directory". This looks like an issue with the "nouveau" driver (see https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1485203 for a similar issue in another Qt application). Can you try NVidia proprietary driver?

Comment: Hey Aurelien :) NVidia proprietary drivers did the trick. I am pretty sure that Genymotion and Nouveau cooperated some time ago but I cannot recall when. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

The solution (the only one?) is to use NVidia proprietary drivers. This seems to be [the case for the Android Emulator as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47900233/linux-run-android-emulator-on-nouveau-driver)